# Python: remove duplicates in list of list ignoring list order

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this

```
[[], [1, 2, 2], [1], [2], [2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

I want to remove all duplicates, where the order does not matter, so in the list above I need to remove `[2]`, `[1,2]`, and `[2,1]`.
I thought I can do this with `Counter()`

```
from collections import Counter
counter_list = []
no_dublicates = []
for sub_list in all_subsets:
    counter_dic = Counter(sub_list)
    if counter_dic in counter_list:
        pass
    else:
        no_dublicates.append(list(sub_list))
        counter_list.append(counter_dic)
```

which works fine... but it is the slowest part of my code. I was wondering whether there is a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the `Counter` objects to `frozenset`s, which are hashable and can be put in a set themselves for linear savings on the `in` check:

```
from collections import Counter

counters = set()
no_duplicates = []

for sub_list in all_subsets:
    c = frozenset(Counter(sub_list).items())

    if c not in counters:
        counters.add(c)
        no_duplicates.append(list(sub_list))
```

Doing this with a dict comprehension also looks cool:

```
no_duplicates = list(
    {frozenset(Counter(l).items()): l for l in all_subsets}.values())
```

Comment: thx... that saved 10%... I guess there is no way to remove the Counter()?

Comment: @carl: You could make a sorted tuple, i.e. `frozenset(Counter(x).items())` → `tuple(sorted(x))`. I don’t know how the performance compares. How are you generating the list? Maybe you can remove duplicates there instead? Avoiding the `list(sub_list)` copy would also probably help.

Comment: @carl you can do without Counter()  check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `collections` module, you can also try a simple solution like this:

```
lsts = [[], [1, 2, 2], [1], [2], [2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

counts = {}
for sublist in lsts:
    key = tuple(sorted(sublist))
    counts[key] = counts.get(key, 0) + 1

result = []
for sublist in lsts:
    key = tuple(sorted(sublist))
    if counts[key] == 1:
        result.append(sublist)

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[], [1, 2, 2], [1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score -2):

Why you are using any external module and why making it too complex when you can do it in just few lines of code:

```
data_=[[], [1, 2, 2], [1], [2], [2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

dta_dict={}
for j,i in enumerate(data_):
    if tuple(sorted(i)) not in dta_dict:
        dta_dict[tuple(sorted(i))]=[j]

    else:
        dta_dict[tuple(sorted(i))].append(j)

print(dta_dict.keys())
```

output:

```
dict_keys([(1, 2), (), (1,), (2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2,)])
```

if you want list instead of tutple :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:list(x),dta_dict.keys())))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [], [1], [2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2]]
```

Comment: This output includes both `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]`.

Comment: You probably read my comment directed at the asker about using `tuple(sorted(x))`, since you commented right beneath it, so why do you feel the need to copy it into an answer…?

Comment: @Ryan ohh i didn't gave attention on that , i implemented my own logic , Now i see that when you pointed out , bdw `tuple(sorted(x))` is just little part , its not main logic.

Comment: @Ryan its ok i don't want to argue , All good my friend no stress.